# Change href property through a Wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to set an `href` property of an `<img>` tag in all the page in my Wordpress site with a value matched in a custom table in the Wordpress database.

Currently, I have written a plugin to fill the database in the plugin setting page and I'm trying to insert the value parsed by the database in the href but I had no luck on understanding how to modify the tag.

All my findings seem related just to create a new tag not to edit one already on the page.

What I need is something similar to GetElementById but in PHP.

I'm trying to do the wrong way?

**EDIT:**

```
function my_the_content_filter() {
    ?>
        <img id='db_image' href='<?php echo $current_image_link; ?>'>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code that you have the problem with, so that we can help.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the relevant code because I'm looking for the method to do that.

Comment: You've written a plugin... you have code that's not working as you want. Please show us the code you are using to try to fix the issue. If we don't know what you've done do far, we can't help.

Comment: use a filter on `the_content` then use something like `PHPQuery` or `DOM` to find the links and replace them ... simple.  I might show you some code, but you haven't shown me any.

Comment: I come up with the code I add in the question.
The issue is that in my case the `<img id='db_image'>` are already in the DOM.
How can I edit it?